# Multimeter capacitance

Tags: measurement

I am using  Multimeter Voltcraft M-4650B to measure the voltage in the test point of a high voltage circuit. I want to find out the stray capacitance of my cable and for that I need to find the capacitance of the multimeter. I am unable to find the datasheet of this partcular model and hence am not able to get the capacitance. If anybody knows the value or knows how to calculate the value kindly let me know.

I also had an idea that I can measure the capacitance of the multimeter using a schering bridge. Will that work?

Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: I don't know your particular meter.  But I'd guess the cable to the meter has most of the capacitance.  Typical coax is ~20 -30 pF/foot.  Or have you already measured the cable.  To measure the meter (crudely) you could use a 'scope and look at the step response as you hit it with a square wave through a known resistor (R<< than Rin of meter.)

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this is to use a separate LCR meter, and attach it to the leads of the multimeter. Then you'll know for sure exactly what capacitance that you are facing. Be sure to repeat this procedure whenever you change leads - different leads can have vastly different capacitances. It also matters greatly whether the lead wires are close together or further apart.